# Completeness and the Completeness Axiom

Tags: real-analysis, complete-spaces

Using the definition, a metric space is **complete** if every Cauchy sequence converges in the metric space.

The **Completeness Axiom** states that every nonempty set of reals that is bounded above has a supremum.

How are these two related? I'm having trouble seeing why one might imply the other, or if they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers#Forms_of_completeness) discusses several forms of completeness for the real numbers, ending with:

> For an ordered field, Cauchy completeness is weaker than the other forms of completeness on this page. But Cauchy completeness and the Archimedean property taken together are equivalent to the others.

Comment: That is, in fact, partly what is confusing me. Does a set that satisfies the LUB property imply Cauchy completeness? It seems not, since the set (0,1), for example, has both a supremum and an infimum, but it is not Cauchy complete since we can define a Cauchy sequence that converges to 0 or 1, which aren't in the set. And Cauchy completeness, based on that quote, does not imply that a set has a LUB.

Comment: @dtkv: The ordered set $(0,1)$ has neither a supremum nor an infimum. However, the subset $(0,1)$ of the ordered set of real numbers does have a supremum and an infimum (in the real numbers).

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. I should have said "interval."

Answer (score 0):

This relation can be inferred from two simple lemmas:
1. Every Cauchy sequence is bounded.
2. Every bounded sequence in Real Numbers has a convergent subsequence.
From these we can infer that in the metric space of real numbers every Cauchy sequence has a convergent Cauchy subsequence. However, using the definition of Cauchy sequences it can be shown that a Cauchy sequence converges iff it has a convergent subsequence. Therefore this implies completeness. Hope this helps.